# Python 2 decimals Points

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, decimal-point

I have a quick question in terms of decimals points in Python 2. 
Here is the code in Python 2:

```
a = 1500/1589
print (round(a,2))
#0.0
```

I thought it would print out a = 0.94 as it did in Python 3. I am just wondering how I could get 2 decimals for my answer.

Comment: what if `a=1500.0/1589.0` ?

Comment: Use `from __future__ import division` to make Python 2 (integer) division work like Python 3 (float) division.  To force integer division in either version, use the operator `//`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thx!!! thats neat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that at least one of the inputs to the division is a floating point number by adding an explicit decimal point.

```
a = 1500. / 1589
print round(a, 2)
# 0.94
```

If you do not do this, both `1500` and `1589` are treated as integers and the result of `1500/1589` is required to be an integer (`0`) as well

```
1500 / 1589
# 0

print round(1500 / 1589, 2)
# 0.0
```

As a side note, if you want to print a number with two decimal places, a far easier method is to create a formatted string:

```
print '%0.2f' % (1500. / 1589)
# 0.94

print '{:.2}'.format(1500. / 1589)
# 0.94
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're making an integer division. For instance do:

```
a = 1500.0/1589.0
print round(a,2)
```

Or if you have integers as input:

```
a = float(1500)/float(1589)
print round(a,2)
```

Comment: Only one number needs to be converted.